# Write a stream of sexy prime pairs in SCHEME

Tags: stream, scheme, primes

I have a SCHEME function is-sexy? which takes one parameter, n, and returns true if n is part of a pair of sexy primes and false otherwise, and a SCHEME function, sexy-primes, which takes an integer, n, as a parameter and returns a list of pairs of prime numbers whose difference is 6 and whose smaller number is less than or equal to n.

How do I define a stream of sexy prime pairs?

```
  (define (is-sexy? n)
  (define (is-prime? x)
    (define (is-prime?-aux x k)
      (cond ((< x 1) #f)
            ((= x k) #t)
            (else
             (if (= (remainder x k) 0) #f
                 (is-prime?-aux x (+ k 1))))))
    (cond ((= x 1) #t)
          ((= x 2) #t)
          (else (is-prime?-aux x 2))))
  (if (and (is-prime? n)
           (or (is-prime? (- n 6)) (is-prime? (+ n 6)))) #t
                                                         #f))

  (define (sexy-primes n)
  (if (= n 0) '()
      (if (is-sexy? n) (cons n (sexy-primes (- n 1)))
          (sexy-primes (- n 1)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
(define (sexyprimes-from k)
  (if (is-sexy? k) (cons (cons k (+ k 6)) (delay (sexyprimes-from (+ k 1))))
   (sexyprimes-from (+ k 1))))
(define sexy-primes (sexyprimes-from 5))
```